Running Selenium scripts on VCR
We have VCR (Virtual Machine) Environment for our testing which only has access to our Internal Applications, now we are planning to build Automation scripts using Cucumber and Selenium in Java. Everything works on Local and now goal is to run these scripts on VCR.
I didn't find much of info on running Automation scripts on VCR, does any one have any experiance around this or share some inside which i can follow.

The main difference between your local pc and VCR is the Maven dependencies. You cannot download the dependencies from the Internet in VCR due to the network restriction.
You can follow these steps to migrate the script to VCR:

Make sure the project runs with Maven successfully on a local pc.
Copy the maven repository folder to the same path on VCR. (usually located at ~/.m2/repository on Unix-like systems or C:\Users<username>.m2\repository on Windows)
Run your scripts.


Thanks @Bin and we are kind of considering similar approach where we are planning to build Single jar first and then refer to that while executing on VCR. I was more over trying to think if anyone able to achieve to that with different approach via Jenkins or any other means..
